# Local Rails server won't start unless sqlite3 is NOT inside development or test block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

I have recently update my Rail 3.2 to 4. Also Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0.

Everything has been working fine for a couple of week and I cannot figure out why I cannot suddenly start my local server.

I get the following error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

My gemfile has **always** has sqlite3 in a

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I can get my local server to work **only** if I move the sqlite3 out of the dev and test group

I've run `bundle check` and all dependencies have been satisfied. 
`bundle install` every single time works.

I also explicitly started the server this way `rails s -e development` and still get the error

Help, please?

Comment: You're starting your app in development environment, right? Your RAILS_ENV isn't set to production or any other value?

Comment: Yep. starting it in dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.yml file and see if you are using right sqlite credentials (if using sqlite DB) to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, check `bundle list` and look for sqlite3. If it's not there, it is not included in your bundle.

Then, keep in mind that the `group` part around the gem definition acts as a filter of sorts. The gem will not be installed if you run something like `bundle install --without development test`.
Even if you are not excluding these environments in the command now: if you ever have, the parameters have been persisted to `./.bundle/config`. Remove it from there and do your fresh install.

Comment: I have two versions of sqlite3... 1.3.8 and 1.3.7... My gemlock says it is using 1.3.8

I've run "bundle isntall" and "bundle update" as well and nothing